# Reshape a tensor to a matrix

Tags: tensors

I have a tensor

```
    T = Array[Subscript[K, ##] &, {2, 2, 2, 2}]
```

And its matrix form is
$$
    \left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
     \left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
     K_{1,1,1,1} & K_{1,1,1,2} \\
     K_{1,1,2,1} & K_{1,1,2,2} \\
    \end{array}
    \right) & \left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
     K_{1,2,1,1} & K_{1,2,1,2} \\
     K_{1,2,2,1} & K_{1,2,2,2} \\
    \end{array}
    \right) \\
     \left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
     K_{2,1,1,1} & K_{2,1,1,2} \\
     K_{2,1,2,1} & K_{2,1,2,2} \\
    \end{array}
    \right) & \left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
     K_{2,2,1,1} & K_{2,2,1,2} \\
     K_{2,2,2,1} & K_{2,2,2,2} \\
    \end{array}
    \right) \\
    \end{array}
    \right)
$$

I use

```
    ArrayReshape[T, {4, 4}]
```

and get the matrix

$$
    \left(
    \begin{array}{cccc}
     K_{1,1,1,1} & K_{1,1,1,2} & K_{1,1,2,1} & K_{1,1,2,2} \\
     K_{1,2,1,1} & K_{1,2,1,2} & K_{1,2,2,1} & K_{1,2,2,2} \\
     K_{2,1,1,1} & K_{2,1,1,2} & K_{2,1,2,1} & K_{2,1,2,2} \\
     K_{2,2,1,1} & K_{2,2,1,2} & K_{2,2,2,1} & K_{2,2,2,2} \\
    \end{array}
    \right).
$$

However, I want the matrix looks exactly like the matrix form of the tensor T. How can I do it in Mathematica?

Ps: This can be done by

```
    ArrayFlatten[T]
```

but When the Dimension of T grows, it doesn't works. For example, if

```
    T = Array[Subscript[K, ##] &, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}]
```

then I need to use

```
    ArrayFlatten[ArrayFlatten[T]]
```

to get the same elements matrix as the matrixform  of the tensor T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
T = Array[Subscript[K, ##] &, {2, 2, 2, 2}];
Flatten[T, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}] // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 K_{1,1,1,1} & K_{1,1,1,2} & K_{1,2,1,1} & K_{1,2,1,2} \\
 K_{1,1,2,1} & K_{1,1,2,2} & K_{1,2,2,1} & K_{1,2,2,2} \\
 K_{2,1,1,1} & K_{2,1,1,2} & K_{2,2,1,1} & K_{2,2,1,2} \\
 K_{2,1,2,1} & K_{2,1,2,2} & K_{2,2,2,1} & K_{2,2,2,2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

```
T = Array[Subscript[K, ##] &, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}];
Flatten[T, {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}}] // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 K_{1,1,1,1,1,1} & K_{1,1,1,1,1,2} & K_{1,1,1,2,1,1} & K_{1,1,1,2,1,2} & K_{1,2,1,1,1,1} & K_{1,2,1,1,1,2} & K_{1,2,1,2,1,1} & K_{1,2,1,2,1,2} \\
 K_{1,1,1,1,2,1} & K_{1,1,1,1,2,2} & K_{1,1,1,2,2,1} & K_{1,1,1,2,2,2} & K_{1,2,1,1,2,1} & K_{1,2,1,1,2,2} & K_{1,2,1,2,2,1} & K_{1,2,1,2,2,2} \\
 K_{1,1,2,1,1,1} & K_{1,1,2,1,1,2} & K_{1,1,2,2,1,1} & K_{1,1,2,2,1,2} & K_{1,2,2,1,1,1} & K_{1,2,2,1,1,2} & K_{1,2,2,2,1,1} & K_{1,2,2,2,1,2} \\
 K_{1,1,2,1,2,1} & K_{1,1,2,1,2,2} & K_{1,1,2,2,2,1} & K_{1,1,2,2,2,2} & K_{1,2,2,1,2,1} & K_{1,2,2,1,2,2} & K_{1,2,2,2,2,1} & K_{1,2,2,2,2,2} \\
 K_{2,1,1,1,1,1} & K_{2,1,1,1,1,2} & K_{2,1,1,2,1,1} & K_{2,1,1,2,1,2} & K_{2,2,1,1,1,1} & K_{2,2,1,1,1,2} & K_{2,2,1,2,1,1} & K_{2,2,1,2,1,2} \\
 K_{2,1,1,1,2,1} & K_{2,1,1,1,2,2} & K_{2,1,1,2,2,1} & K_{2,1,1,2,2,2} & K_{2,2,1,1,2,1} & K_{2,2,1,1,2,2} & K_{2,2,1,2,2,1} & K_{2,2,1,2,2,2} \\
 K_{2,1,2,1,1,1} & K_{2,1,2,1,1,2} & K_{2,1,2,2,1,1} & K_{2,1,2,2,1,2} & K_{2,2,2,1,1,1} & K_{2,2,2,1,1,2} & K_{2,2,2,2,1,1} & K_{2,2,2,2,1,2} \\
 K_{2,1,2,1,2,1} & K_{2,1,2,1,2,2} & K_{2,1,2,2,2,1} & K_{2,1,2,2,2,2} & K_{2,2,2,1,2,1} & K_{2,2,2,1,2,2} & K_{2,2,2,2,2,1} & K_{2,2,2,2,2,2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Et cetera. For example, for a rank-8 tensor,

```
n = 8;
T = Array[Subscript[K, ##] &, ConstantArray[2, n]];
Flatten[T, {Range[1, n, 2], Range[2, n, 2]}] // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 K_{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} & K_{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2} & K_{1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1} & K_{1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2} & K_{1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1} & K_{1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2} &
   K_{1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1} & K_{1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2} & K_{1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1} & K_{1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2} & K_{1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1} & K_{1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2} &
   K_{1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1} & K_{1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2} & K_{1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1} & K_{1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2} \\
 K_{1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1} & K_{1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2} & K_{1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1} & K_{1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2} & K_{1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1} & K_{1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2} &
   K_{1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1} & K_{1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2} & K_{1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1} & K_{1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2} & K_{1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1} & K_{1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2} &
   K_{1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1} & K_{1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2} & K_{1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1} & K_{1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2} \\
 K_{1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1} & K_{1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2} & K_{1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1} & K_{1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2} & K_{1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1} & K_{1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2} &
   K_{1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1} & K_{1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2} & K_{1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1} & K_{1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2} & K_{1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1} & K_{1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2} &
   K_{1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1} & K_{1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2} & K_{1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1} & K_{1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2} \\
 K_{1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1} & K_{1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2} & K_{1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1} & K_{1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2} & K_{1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1} & K_{1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2} &
   K_{1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1} & K_{1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2} & K_{1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1} & K_{1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2} & K_{1,2,1,1,2,2,2,1} & K_{1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2} &
   K_{1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1} & K_{1,2,1,2,2,1,2,2} & K_{1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1} & K_{1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2} \\
 K_{1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1} & K_{1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2} & K_{1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1} & K_{1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2} & K_{1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1} & K_{1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2} &
   K_{1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1} & K_{1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2} & K_{1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1} & K_{1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2} & K_{1,2,2,1,1,2,1,1} & K_{1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2} &
   K_{1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1} & K_{1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2} & K_{1,2,2,2,1,2,1,1} & K_{1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2} \\
 K_{1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1} & K_{1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2} & K_{1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1} & K_{1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2} & K_{1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1} & K_{1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2} &
   K_{1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1} & K_{1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2} & K_{1,2,2,1,1,1,2,1} & K_{1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2} & K_{1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1} & K_{1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2} &
   K_{1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1} & K_{1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2} & K_{1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1} & K_{1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2} \\
 K_{1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1} & K_{1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2} & K_{1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1} & K_{1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2} & K_{1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1} & K_{1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2} &
   K_{1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1} & K_{1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2} & K_{1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1} & K_{1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2} & K_{1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1} & K_{1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2} &
   K_{1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1} & K_{1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2} & K_{1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1} & K_{1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2} \\
 K_{1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1} & K_{1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2} & K_{1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1} & K_{1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2} & K_{1,1,2,2,2,1,2,1} & K_{1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2} &
   K_{1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1} & K_{1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2} & K_{1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1} & K_{1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2} & K_{1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1} & K_{1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2} &
   K_{1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1} & K_{1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2} & K_{1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1} & K_{1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2} \\
 K_{2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} & K_{2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2} & K_{2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1} & K_{2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2} & K_{2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1} & K_{2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2} &
   K_{2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1} & K_{2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2} & K_{2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1} & K_{2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2} & K_{2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1} & K_{2,2,1,1,1,2,1,2} &
   K_{2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1} & K_{2,2,1,2,1,1,1,2} & K_{2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1} & K_{2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2} \\
 K_{2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1} & K_{2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2} & K_{2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1} & K_{2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2} & K_{2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1} & K_{2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2} &
   K_{2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1} & K_{2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2} & K_{2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1} & K_{2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2} & K_{2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1} & K_{2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2} &
   K_{2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1} & K_{2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2} & K_{2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1} & K_{2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2} \\
 K_{2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1} & K_{2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2} & K_{2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1} & K_{2,1,1,1,2,2,1,2} & K_{2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1} & K_{2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2} &
   K_{2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1} & K_{2,1,1,2,2,2,1,2} & K_{2,2,1,1,2,1,1,1} & K_{2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2} & K_{2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1} & K_{2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2} &
   K_{2,2,1,2,2,1,1,1} & K_{2,2,1,2,2,1,1,2} & K_{2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1} & K_{2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2} \\
 K_{2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1} & K_{2,1,1,1,2,1,2,2} & K_{2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1} & K_{2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2} & K_{2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1} & K_{2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2} &
   K_{2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1} & K_{2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2} & K_{2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1} & K_{2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2} & K_{2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1} & K_{2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2} &
   K_{2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1} & K_{2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2} & K_{2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1} & K_{2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2} \\
 K_{2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1} & K_{2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2} & K_{2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1} & K_{2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2} & K_{2,1,2,2,1,1,1,1} & K_{2,1,2,2,1,1,1,2} &
   K_{2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1} & K_{2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2} & K_{2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1} & K_{2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2} & K_{2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1} & K_{2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2} &
   K_{2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1} & K_{2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2} & K_{2,2,2,2,1,2,1,1} & K_{2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2} \\
 K_{2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1} & K_{2,1,2,1,1,1,2,2} & K_{2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1} & K_{2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2} & K_{2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1} & K_{2,1,2,2,1,1,2,2} &
   K_{2,1,2,2,1,2,2,1} & K_{2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2} & K_{2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1} & K_{2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2} & K_{2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1} & K_{2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2} &
   K_{2,2,2,2,1,1,2,1} & K_{2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2} & K_{2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1} & K_{2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2} \\
 K_{2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1} & K_{2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2} & K_{2,1,2,1,2,2,1,1} & K_{2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2} & K_{2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1} & K_{2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2} &
   K_{2,1,2,2,2,2,1,1} & K_{2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2} & K_{2,2,2,1,2,1,1,1} & K_{2,2,2,1,2,1,1,2} & K_{2,2,2,1,2,2,1,1} & K_{2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2} &
   K_{2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1} & K_{2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2} & K_{2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1} & K_{2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2} \\
 K_{2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1} & K_{2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2} & K_{2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1} & K_{2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2} & K_{2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1} & K_{2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2} &
   K_{2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1} & K_{2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2} & K_{2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1} & K_{2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2} & K_{2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1} & K_{2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2} &
   K_{2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1} & K_{2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2} & K_{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1} & K_{2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: How to do the inverse operation? From the Matrix to the same arrange tensor?

Comment: The inverse can be done by ``` Partition[Flatten[T, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}] , {2, 2}]```!

Comment: But for the high dimension, I need to do Partition[Partition[...]]. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please ask a separate question.